# How to retrieving data from database using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, sql-server-2005

When I'm using this I'm getting java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.transgenomic.domain.Note error showing

```
public List<Note> getNoteDescription(Long userId) {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
    SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT n.description"
         + " FROM notes n, users u, tasks t "
         + " where u.userId=t.assignTo AND t.taskId=n.taskId");

    List<Note> notes=query.list();
    System.out.println("***********"+notes);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
    return notes;
}
```

Comment: It is easy with `Hibernate Criteria`.If you post your mapping we can help you easyly

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate returns a raw List from the Query.list method.

You are doing an unsafe cast from `List<?>` to `List<Note>` - this cannot be avoided.

The only way to make the error go away is:

```
List<Note> list = new LinkedList<>();
for(Note n : query.list()) {
    list.add((Note));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:
Change your select from `SELECT n.description` into `SELECT n`
or
change your method return type and type of `notes` from `List<Note>` into `List<String>`

Assuming type of "description" is `String`, using `SELECT n.description` will return that field only, hence query.list() will return List, this doesn't match the expected `List<Note>`

Using `SELECT n` means returning the whole object